# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path occurs when testing controller method

Tags: java, jackson, junit5, jsonpath, mockmvc

I wrote a test using JUnit 5 that passed successfully when the controller method returned a User in the response body. After modifying the method to return a UserDto the test fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.email"..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
```

This is the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserControllerTest  {

    @Autowired
    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    protected MvcResult mvcResult;

    @Autowired
    public JacksonTester<T> jacksonTester;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    private static final User secondExpectedUser = new User(2, 
        "user2@gmail.com", "user2", Collections.emptyList(), List.of(USER));
    private static final UserDto secondExpectedUserDto = new UserDto(2, 
         "user2@gmail.com", Collections.emptyList(), List.of(USER));


    @Test
    void addUser_Returns_CREATED_user() throws Exception {
        mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
                .content(jacksonTester.write(secondExpectedUser).getJson())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(secondExpectedUserDto.getEmail()))
                .andReturn();

        String actualUserJson = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(actualUserJson).isNotEmpty();
    }
```

And this is the method being tested:

```
  @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws SQLException {
        UserDto userDto = userService.addUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

In userService the code looks like this:

```
  public void addUsers(String fileName) throws SQLException, IOException, UserNotFoundException {
        List<User> users = getAllUsersFromFile(fileName);
        userRepository.addUsers(users);
        Logger.info("Users successfully added to the database.");
    }
```

The UserDto is returned by addUser() method from UserRepository in which I made the mapping.
I mention that both UserDto and User contain the 'email' attribute.

What I tried to do:

I tried to add [0] in jsonPath because I thought maybe it interprets the body of my response as a list but it was not it.
`.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].email").value(secondExpectedUserDto.getEmail()))`

I also tried to use another field instead of 'email' in expect method, but I got the same error.

I assumed the problem is caused by an incorrect mapping of User to UserDto.
I tried to use a ModelMapper to mock the objects mapping, so I added these into my pom.xml, class and into begining of the test method but I still got the same error.

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
    @MockBean
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

```
    when(modelMapper.map(any(User.class), eq(UserDto.class))).thenReturn(secondExpectedUserDto);
    modelMapper.map(secondExpectedUser, secondExpectedUserDto);
```

I don't know what else to try, please let me know if you notice something wrong in my approach or if you have encountered the same problem.

Comment: Not all relevant code is shown, eg „secondExpectedUser“ comes from nowhere. I suggest you start by adding the full test class - at least the parts touched in the failing test.

Comment: @johanneslink I edited my question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Where is the userService mock being configured? Without explicit setup it’s returning null by default, which COULD be an explanation for what you see.

Comment: You are right, after adding when(userService.addUser(any())).thenReturn(secondExpectedUserDto)  on the first line of my test it passed. Thank you, @johaneeslink !